# SQL-Injection file upload when database and webserver are on different machines

Tags: sql-injection

I have two servers, one for the database (mysql) and one for the website (apache) and there is a sql injection on my web application. Is it possible now to upload a shell to my webserver or does the file_read, INTO outfile, INTO dumpfile, etc. only work on the database server?

Is it possible to upload a shell to the webserver when database and webserver are on different machines?

Answer (score 1):

Everything depend on how you separate the data from web application code.

The answer is a **YES** for most of the Web CMS (Content management System) that allow developer to put code directly into the CMS and execute the code on the fly.

If your web application doesn't use on-the-fly generated CMS , and you sanitize the data transfer from the database (which doesn't render any data as script) ,then the answer is **NO**.

(update)

Attacker can upload ANYTHING they want to the DATABASE server once they successful perform the SQL injection. **Theoretically**, SQL injection **WILL NOT** compromised the web server integrity (it doesn't matter whether web server reside in the same server or not).

HOWEVER, many website are using CMS, that will use some sort of database itself. Once CMS database is compromised, it will also affect the web server, that's why I mentioned the data separation.

I.e. 
Imagine you have a separate database server, your web server will read data from database and will render it directly, without sanitize.  So now the database is compromised by SQL injection,  and since you didn't sanitize data from database, when the attacker upload web server compatible shell code to the database, your web server will happily execute those code.

Comment: Maybe I didnt write clear enough what I wanted to know, however, my question is, if it is possible to upload a shell through an sql injection to the webserver when the database and the webserver are on different server machines.